# Background image via css-loader in webpak

Tags: webpack, background, background-image, css-loader

I have such css-style in div-element:

```
.header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url("../../assets/bg.jpg");
}
```

After building it looks like css-loader in webpack create a new file in output with extension .jpg and change css due to it:

```
.header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url(0053f91466b237c7ea79.jpg);
}
```

The file 0053f91466b237c7ea79.jpg is not image, it contains the string `export default __webpack_public_path__ + "bg.jpg";` only.

At the same time, the file-loader extracts this image bg.jpg correctly.

*webpack.config.js*

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./index.js",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              url: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[name].[ext]",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js"],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin(), new MiniCssExtractPlugin()],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the version of `css-loader` which causes this problem. Using the older version of `css-loader`(e.g.:3.4.2), the correct image and image url can be created via `file-loader`. But the latest version of `css-loader` make something wrong when it works with `file-loader`. After building, it looks like `css-loader` in webpack create a new file in output with correct image and change css. And `file-loader` rewrite the content of that image and extracts another correct image.

Solution:

1. Removed `file-loader` from your webpack.config.js
2. Use the older version of `css-loader`